# How difficult would it be to get a uniform DataReader for portable class?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I would like to use a single interface for data reading across the platforms supported by MvvmCross. In particular, creating and consuming DataReaders derived from IDataReader. It seems that the question is whether we can call the Windows Store version and the original Net45 System.Data version with similar calls, or if they are so different that this will be very challenging. Any insight or leads would be much appreciated.

Would it be easier to create a Windows.Storage-like implementation or to create a System-Data-like implementation?

**Update.** https://github.com/UbiqRT/Storage seems to have the vision, but not really started

Comment: As part of my porting work of two image processing frameworks to PCL, I have made an extremely rudimentary implementation of some of the basic `System.Data` classes, see [here](https://github.com/cureos/aforge/tree/master/Sources/System/Data), just to ensure that the PCL can build the classes that incorporate `System.Data` functionality. I'd love to see someone taking on the challenge and create a more complete PCL `Portable.System.Data` library :-) including suitable `DataReader`:s and similar.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about concepts of architecture which fit better on programmers.stackexchange.com